# How to solve ls: reading directory '.': Input/output error for specific directory

Tags: ubuntu, mount, ntfs

I have a 5TB external drive, with two partitions. Suddenly one of the partitions gives me this error `data: unknown error when mounting /dev/sda1`. I solved this error based on this  [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/696648/898329).

After running `sudo ntfsfix /dev/sda1`, it allows me to access the drive and all directories work fine except the directory called `JS`. The size of `JS` is around 1.1TB, when I run `ls -la` command it gives me this error `ls: reading directory '.': Input/output error`.

**Note**: I looked at drive size 80% is used (the same as before the problem) meaning my data are still there.

How to fix this issue?

Comment: Anything in `dmesg`? Can you find a spare Windows PC and run `chkdsk D:` or whatever? I'd not recommend using `ntfsfix` ever: *ntfsfix is a utility that fixes some common NTFS problems.  ntfsfix is NOT a Linux version of chkdsk.  It only repairs some fundamental NTFS inconsistencies, resets the NTFS journal file and schedules an NTFS consistency check for the first boot into Windows.* It hides errors if anything.

Comment: I run `chkdsk  h: /f /r`  in windowa 11. After around 1 hour, the terminal stack in `Stage 4: Looking for bad clusters in user file data. Progress: 56 of 35884 done;`.  It seems it needs years to finish :( What should I do if it remains like that? what will happen to my data if I cancel the operation?

Comment: That's OK to cancel it, the `/r` option checks if the data is readable. Please try it again on your Linux PC. If you're running a sufficiently new kernel, I'd recommend giving the native NTFS driver a try, it's called `ntfs3`. Please check `dmesg` logs for IO errors if the issues persists with `ntfs3` as well. The driver is not yet perfect but it's a lot faster, specially when dealing with lots of files or small files.

Comment: "_I solved the problem based on this answer._" - are you saying there's no longer an issue? Since you've not got any answers yet please consider either deleting the question so noone spends more effort on it, or write your own answer and accept it

Comment: The OP probably meant "I tried to solve the issue".

Comment: @roaima, when I said the problem, I meant the first error (data: unknown error when mounting /dev/sda1). I edited the question.

Comment: Thank you. It really wasn't clear to me